# Windows limitation in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, window

Is there any limitation of count of opened windows in IE 8?
Using web site I am opening 1 window (`window.open()`), then from it another (modal), from it another (not modal), then another (modal). Here I can't open another one window from the last modal.
When I clicked open new window button from the last modal dialog, its parent window begin loading. When I closed last modal window, its parent loads the url, which I want to be opened in new window.
So:
1) (main window) -> (window) -> (modal) -> (window) -> (modal) -> (window is not opened, url `A`)
2) (main window) -> (window) -> (modal) -> (window) -> (close this modal)
3) (main window) -> (window) -> (modal) -> (window loads url `A`)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you giving all these windows different names? You could try specifying a unique window name in the windows.open() command.

Comment: No, many of them has empty name. Is it important for IE? Hm, but first 4 windows is opened successfully... So, I'll try to set names.